# Memory allocation is based on reference class or instance class?

Tags: java, memory-management

I have a very dump question in java.  The memory allocation for every java object in heap will be based on the reference class or instance class?

```
    public static void main(String[] a){
    MemoryParent parChild = new MemoryChild();
}
```

In the above example, the memory allocation for the object parChild is based on MemoryChild or MemoryParent?  I guess its based on instance class MemoryChild.  Could somebody clarify this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An instance of `MemoryChild` is what's present on the heap

Comment: Its been answered so I'll leave this as a comment: this example is simply too unrealistic. See it as Animal animal = new Cow(); then you -know- what the answer is, no need to guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The allocation of memory happens when you call `new`.  Hence, the memory allocated is the size of `MemoryChild`.

This is good, because `MemoryParent` could be much smaller than `MemoryChild`.

Answer (score 2):

It's based on the type it is, not the type it's referred to by. In your case, the object *is* a `MemoryChild`, so that object is used.

Think of it this way: If I refer to you as "new SO user," you're still "@Subbu." Just because I *refer* to you by a different type doesn't change what you are.

Answer (score 0):

It is of the type MemoryChild and so take up the space that MemoryChild takes up, runs the methods MemoryChild has and so on.

In the code you write, however, you will only be allowed to treat it as a MemoryParent, so if you have methods on MemoryChild that you have *not* declared in MemoryParent you can't call them.

So basically the MemoryParent is the *static*, or compile time, type of parChild, while MemoryChild is the *dynamic*, or run time, type of parChild.

Answer (score 0):

```
MemoryParent parChild = new MemoryChild();
```

This means `creating object of MemoryChild and Assigning to Reference of super class  MemoryParent.`

So the **memory allocation based instance class** rather than which type of class it refers.

To know more in detail about memory allocation please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897784/how-is-physical-memory-organized-between-base-and-derived-class-instances-in-jav) question.